# Unable to start JBoss from within Eclipse

Tags: eclipse, jboss

I am unable to start JBoss server 5.1.0.GA version from eclipse Indigo.

Eclipse shows me message box saying '**Server JBoss v5.0 at localhost was unable to start within 500 seconds. If the server requires more time, try increasing the timeout in the server editor.**' but in the console window I can see that JBoss has been actually started.

here is some part of log which I can see in console window of eclipse :

```
    SecureDeploymentManager/remote - EJB3.x Default Remote Business Interface
    SecureDeploymentManager/remote-org.jboss.deployers.spi.management.deploy.DeploymentManager - EJB3.x Remote Business Interface

15:14:20,212 INFO  [SessionSpecContainer] Starting jboss.j2ee:jar=profileservice-secured.jar,name=SecureManagementView,service=EJB3
15:14:20,212 INFO  [EJBContainer] STARTED EJB: org.jboss.profileservice.ejb.SecureManagementView ejbName: SecureManagementView
15:14:20,222 INFO  [JndiSessionRegistrarBase] Binding the following Entries in Global JNDI:

    SecureManagementView/remote - EJB3.x Default Remote Business Interface
    SecureManagementView/remote-org.jboss.deployers.spi.management.ManagementView - EJB3.x Remote Business Interface

15:14:20,252 INFO  [SessionSpecContainer] Starting jboss.j2ee:jar=profileservice-secured.jar,name=SecureProfileService,service=EJB3
15:14:20,262 INFO  [EJBContainer] STARTED EJB: org.jboss.profileservice.ejb.SecureProfileServiceBean ejbName: SecureProfileService
15:14:20,272 INFO  [JndiSessionRegistrarBase] Binding the following Entries in Global JNDI:

    SecureProfileService/remote - EJB3.x Default Remote Business Interface
    SecureProfileService/remote-org.jboss.profileservice.spi.ProfileService - EJB3.x Remote Business Interface

15:14:20,362 INFO  [TomcatDeployment] deploy, ctxPath=/admin-console
15:14:20,412 INFO  [config] Initializing Mojarra (1.2_12-b01-FCS) for context '/admin-console'
15:14:23,486 INFO  [TomcatDeployment] deploy, ctxPath=/BannedListSearch
15:14:27,532 INFO  [TomcatDeployment] deploy, ctxPath=/IWorkWebApp
15:14:27,813 INFO  [TomcatDeployment] deploy, ctxPath=/
15:14:29,155 INFO  [TomcatDeployment] deploy, ctxPath=/TestWebProject
15:14:30,036 INFO  [TomcatDeployment] deploy, ctxPath=/displaytag-examples-1.2
15:14:30,136 INFO  [TomcatDeployment] deploy, ctxPath=/jmx-console
15:14:30,276 INFO  [TomcatDeployment] deploy, ctxPath=/HelloWebService
15:14:30,407 ERROR [EngineConfigurationFactoryServlet] Unable to find config file.  Creating new servlet engine config file: /WEB-INF/server-config.wsdd
15:14:30,687 INFO  [Http11Protocol] Starting Coyote HTTP/1.1 on http-127.0.0.1-8081
15:14:30,707 INFO  [AjpProtocol] Starting Coyote AJP/1.3 on ajp-127.0.0.1-8009
15:14:30,707 INFO  [ServerImpl] JBoss (Microcontainer) [5.1.0.GA (build: SVNTag=JBoss_5_1_0_GA date=200905221053)] Started in 48s:110ms
```

I have increased start Timeout of server to 500 seconds then also I am getting same error. I have not changed anything else.

I am able to start JBoss from command prompt successfully but same server is not getting started from eclipse.

Please help me to start the JBoss server.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Sound to me like the http port you are configured in JBoss is different to the port you have in the Eclipse configuration for JBoss.

Eclipse uses the port configuration to listen to JBoss' port so that it can determine that JBoss has actually started. If they differ, Eclipse thinks JBoss has never started although it actually has according to the log console. Make the ports match and it will probably work.

**Updated:** According to your log, JBoss is using port 8081 for HTTP:

```
Starting Coyote HTTP/1.1 on http-127.0.0.1-8081
```

Now you have to tell Eclipse to listen to that port so that it can figure out whether JBoss has started (default is 8080 and therefore Eclipse will never be aware of it!). Go to your servers view, double click on your JBoss server, and the configuration screen will come up:

[image]

You have to edit the HTTP port (in the 'Port' box) and set it to 8081 so that it matches your server's.

Comment: Hi Gonzalo Garcia, how to make sure ports match?

Comment: I was having the same problem... resolved with this suggestion .. thanks a lot :)

Comment: You can try to change the port in JBoss config file, for example in JBoss 5 you must change the "port" property in binding.xml

Answer (score 0):

The problem which I have encountered is as below and I also give you detailed steps to resolve this problem.

**Error** - *Server Red Hat JBoss EAP 6.1+ was unable to start within 450 seconds. If the server requires more time, try increasing the timeout in the server editor.*

**Root Cause** - Depending upon the version of Jboss the generated log may be different. In my case, I received the below log and I understood that the port which the server was using was already in use as it was already started previously, but it could not stop properly. In order to stop the services which jboss is using, we need to find the port and kill the process which is using that port.

```
15:27:02,440 ERROR [org.apache.coyote.ajp] (MSC service thread 1-15) JBWEB003043: Error initializing endpoint: java.net.BindException: **Address already in use: JVM_Bind /0.0.0.0:8009**
at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.JIoEndpoint.init(JIoEndpoint.java:979) [jbossweb-7.5.16.Final-redhat-1.jar:7.5.16.Final-redhat-1]
at org.apache.coyote.ajp.AjpProtocol.init(AjpProtocol.java:153) [jbossweb-7.5.16.Final-redhat-1.jar:7.5.16.Final-redhat-1]
at org.apache.catalina.connector.Connector.init(Connector.java:986) [jbossweb-7.5.16.Final-redhat-1.jar:7.5.16.Final-redhat-1]
at org.jboss.as.web.WebConnectorService.start(WebConnectorService.java:318) [jboss-as-web-7.5.8.Final-redhat-2.jar:7.5.8.Final-redhat-2]
at org.jboss.msc.service.ServiceControllerImpl$StartTask.startService(ServiceControllerImpl.java:1980) [jboss-msc-1.1.5.Final-redhat-1.jar:1.1.5.Final-redhat-1]
at org.jboss.msc.service.ServiceControllerImpl$StartTask.run(ServiceControllerImpl.java:1913) [jboss-msc-1.1.5.Final-redhat-1.jar:1.1.5.Final-redhat-1]
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1145) [rt.jar:1.7.0_80]
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:615) [rt.jar:1.7.0_80]
at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745) [rt.jar:1.7.0_80]
```

**Resolution** -

**Unix users:**
In most Linux distributions you can use the following command to find PID-Process Name information for one user:

$ netstat -tulpn | grep 8009
tcp 0 0 127.0.0.1:8080 0.0.0.0:* LISTEN 22005/java

Another powerful tool is fuser which can check the processes using TCP/UDP sockets. Here is how to check which process binds a TCP Socket on port 8009:

$ fuser -v -n tcp 8080

**Windows users:**

You can use netstat to get network information for all processes. In the following example we make a filter on port 8080:

netstat -ano | find "8080"

You will be able to detect the process that is engaging your Port. Assuming that your PID is 1234, in order to kill it you can execute:

taskkill -pid 1234 /f

Comment: My question was posted in 2011, 11 years before. People still use JBoss? :D